# Static are not loaded during the deploy

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

Static are not loaded during the deploy. `collectstatic` was success (I see static dir with all of files on the server).

docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.7'

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.4
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  web:
    image: maskalev/foodgram
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - static_value:/code/static/
      - media_value:/code/media/
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./.env
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.3
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - static_value:/var/html/static/
      - media_value:/var/html/media/
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_value:
  media_value:
```

nginx/default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1 x.x.x.x;
    location /static/ {
        root /var/html/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /var/html/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }
}
```

I see messages like this:

```
nginx_1  | 2021/07/30 04:55:12 [error] 28#28: *7 open() "/var/html/static/pages/indexAuth.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: y.y.y.y, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /static/pages/indexAuth.js HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x", referrer: "http://x.x.x.x/"
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Make sure you set STATIC_URL & STATIC_ROOT correctly in settings.

Comment: settings.py  BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent  STATIC_URL = '/static/'  STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'